# Overriding or Changing Admin Templates in Django 1.11

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

My general goal is to make the data in `/admin/my_app/my_model/<id>/change/` not editable or the link that goes to that page to go to another URL that's just `view` instead of `change`.

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to extend these templates. A lot of tutorials and docs I see talks of changing the templates in `/templates/admin` but I get the feeling that that's been deprecated in 1.11.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not deprecated. Just copy `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list_results.html` (it describes each line of models list) to your own project's `templates/admin/` and change it as you wish, by example add column with your link at the end of row. But beware of writing some model specific stuff as it will spread to all your models. If you still need it, store this stuff in model classes.

Another point is that Django Admin app is not intended for just viewing data, it's main purpose to edit it. Just have a quick look inside source files and you will understand that point.

All you can do is to change custom ModelAdmin class and forbid adding and deletion by overriding `has_add_permission` and `has_delete_permission` methods and set all your fields to read-only, but still you will see Save buttons everywhere. If that is not an option for you, declare your custom view inside of ModelAdmin or AdminSite class and add it to admin site urls.